# How to click more Items in a Spinner and higlight it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner, highlight

I programmed a spinner in kotlin which loads different Items in it. It closes automatically when one Item gets touched. How can I programm it, so that it doesn't close when one is selected, but when I tip somewhere else? 
And I could not find a programming solution to highlight the selceted Items in the spinner.

Here my code for the spinner:

```
 Busliste.add("alle anzeigen")                                                                       
    val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
    val dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Busliste)
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.adapter = dataAdapter

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            println(position)
            if (position>0) {
                Routennummer=Busliste[position].subSequence(6,Busliste[position].length).toString().toInt()
                println("Routennummer ist "+Routennummer)
                RouteAuslesen()
                LinieAuslesen()
            }
            if (position==0){
                Routennummer =0
            }
            RouteAuslesen()
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            //do nothing
            println("nothing selected")
        }

    }
```

thank you beforehand

Comment: Use custom spinner with checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can create a custom spinner which contains a checkbox and text files inside it. So that you can select more than one value inside your spinner.**

To implement custom spinner with checkbox follow the below link-

https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/